# Dealing with asynchronous http calls node js

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous

I have a RESTish api on a node js server. When it receives a GET request, it is to call a function that will then be calling another server get function. The code looks like this:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log("YEAHHH! ", request.method);
    var string='';
    // Inside a request handler method
    if (request.method == "OPTIONS") {
        console.log("options");
        // Add headers to response and send
        //response.writeHead(statusCode, responseHeaders);
        response.writeHead(success,responseHeaders);
        response.end();
    }
    if(request.method == "GET") {
        string = soso();
    }

    console.log("*******", string);
    response.writeHead(success,responseHeaders);
    response.end(string);
});
```

`soso()` is the call to the other server. The issue is I want to send the response of the soso() function before its finished so all I'm getting is an empty string.

How do I get around this?

I'm sure this is a duplicate but can't quite find what I'm looking for. So, any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Code for the soso function:

```
var soso = function () {
    console.log("this is being called");
    var options = {...}

    var req = https.get( options, function(res)  {
        var str = '';
        res.on('data', function ( chunk ) {
            str += chunk;
        })

        res.on('end', function () {
            console.log ( "str is: ", str );
            string = str;
        })

        req.end();
        console.log(res.statusCode);
        console.log(responseHeaders);
    });

}
```

Comment: Where's the code for `soso()`?

Comment: It appears that what you're trying to do is make a proxy for some other server.  There is lots and lots of pre-existing code to do just this.

Comment: @jfriend000 any links to a personal favorite?

Comment: I haven't used any myself, but this one looks promising: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy.  Or, you could just use nginx by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this , I am not sure. I have not tested this. Pass the response object in soso function, then use `response.end(string);` after get request gets end.

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        console.log("YEAHHH! ", request.method);
        var string='';
        // Inside a request handler method
        if (request.method == "OPTIONS") {
            console.log("options");
            // Add headers to response and send
            //response.writeHead(statusCode, responseHeaders);
            response.writeHead(success,responseHeaders);
            response.end();
        }
        if(request.method == "GET") {
            string = soso(response);   //send response object as argument
        } else {
     console.log("*******", string);
        response.writeHead(success,responseHeaders);
        response.end(string);
    }


    });
```

**soso function**

```
var soso = fuction(response){ // we pass the response object in soso function
    console.log("this is being called");
        var options = {...}

        var req = https.get( options, function(res)  {
            var str = '';
            res.on('data', function ( chunk ) {
                str += chunk;
            })

            res.on('end', function () {
                console.log ( "str is: ", str );
                string = str;
            })

            req.end();
     response.writeHead(success,responseHeaders);  
        response.end(string);
            console.log(res.statusCode);
            console.log(responseHeaders);
        });

}
```